# Who can review my code if I'm the only one that knows the technology?

Tags: code-reviews

I'm currently working on introducing React in the company I work for. As the only one having done courses on the topic, who can I ask for a review to make sure the code is following 'best practices' and is implemented correctly?

Comment: Aside: companies should *not* strive to reduce the bus factor to one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make being code reviewed by someone who doesn't know the language easier?](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/196212/how-can-i-make-being-code-reviewed-by-someone-who-doesnt-know-the-language-easi)

Comment: Um, have the other developers take React courses?

Comment: @gnat Not a duplicate, but they are related. That question is asking what to do to make it easier for reviewers unfamiliar with a language. This one is asking who should be chosen to be part of the review.

Comment: @ThomasOwens you have a point, upon re-reading it looks like a bit different question (retracted duplicate vote)

Comment: Ignorance (but not too much maybe!) is a legitimate perspective for a code review. And I don't mean merely code formatting flame wars.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There are [other reasons to do a code review](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/255945/4). If you have developers who are familiar with similar technologies, it may be useful to hold a code review meeting where you walkthrough the code and use it as a learning experience for the rest of the team. Their questions about what you are doing may help you find problems in your own code by talking through what you implemented and how you implemented it.

Comment: Team rubberducking? :)

Comment: @NicklasWinger Essentially, yes. Although hopefully your coworkers are more engaged and talkative than a rubber duck.