# Code review if nobody in team has knowledge in some technology?

Tags: java, development-process, code-quality, ios, code-reviews

Sample situation: A team of Java developers starts an iOS project. Only one developer has Objective-C/iOS knowledge, and in the beginning he will work on this project alone.

How we can perform code reviews in this situation? What are processes, approaches, tools that this developer will use?

Comment: As a guess, I'd use the same processes & approaches as with any other code, but plan on more time for the review.

Comment: What's the actual situation you are facing? It's frowned upon to ask hypothetical questions on SO. Are you actually doing this? Also, please don't be lazy. Punctuate properly.

Comment: Easy peasy. Author should sit along with reviewer and explain what's going on there in code, until reviewer says _OK I got it_. That would probably be the best way of knowledge transfer one can think of

Comment: If you are not thinking of Code Reviews as a training tool as well as for other functions, you are doing them wrong. This is one of the primary reasons fro CR.

Comment: @mattnz I disagree with this statement.  The reviewer is not always matched or superior in skill and knowledge as the developer. Often times as a reviewer myself, I learned a new way of approaching an old problem.  This may not directly help the code, but the team is overall stronger because of it.

Comment: @maple_shaft: I wasn't clear enough - the review gets people together so all learn. I personally expect at review time - (no matter who's work is being reviewed) to learn something, no matter how experienced the other person is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The same process would go for any development. I understand and agree it would be, little more work in a new technology, but once you create few test cases, you will be basically eyeing for same errors(Mathematical/Logical/) as in other technologies.

So,

1. List all the test cases.
2. Discuss it with your peers. (Team Work is very important here.)
3. If possible join some groups in apple developers (for Objective C) and look for more information.
4. Also look for some more information in SE.

This link will help you get more information on the same.
[Code Review](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/33968/how-to-review-code-that-you-do-not-understand)

Answer (score 10):

In this situation, code reviews would be a great way to spread Objective-C/iOS knowledge throughout the team, so that someone else can fix bugs when the iOS developer goes on a honeymoon/quits in a huff/gets hit by a bus/is moved to a higher priority project.

Finding bugs is only half the value of code reviews. Spreading knowledge (about both the technology and the solution implemented) is the other half.

Besides, a decent Java developer may well spot logic errors/etc. in Objective-C code.  Just the act of saying "So why do you do this here?" can easily cause the original developer to spot something himself.

Answer (score 1):

First off, Code Review is not compilation -- it is not used to check syntax, but rather logic and design patterns/conventions.  And while there are design patterns that are somewhat platform/language specific, there are more that aren't.  Your developers should pickup enough of the syntax in order to be able to aid in spotting both logic and design issues.

Basically I think this is a non-problem -- instead, I think it's an opportunity for your Java developers to get their feet wet in the language while providing good service.